# PHP find min value of key in xml

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I'm new in PHP, so I need some help because I cant find my error. Here is my xml file:

```
<children>
    <child id="A">
        <link id="C" age="10" />
        <link id="B" age="13" />
        <link id="H" age="12" />
    </child>
    <child id="B">
        <link id="C" age="10" />
        <link id="D" age="50" />
    </child>
    <child id="C">
        <link id="I" age="50" />
    </child>
</children>
```

Here is my php code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$arr = (array) $xml;
function find_youngest($task_1, $task_2) {
    if ($task_1['age'] === $task_2['age']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $task_1['age'] - $task_2['age'];
}
foreach ($arr as &$key) {
    usort($key, 'find_youngest');
}
var_dump($arr[0]);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

I want to get youngest people in each element and the result should be like this:

```
<link id1="A" id2="C" />
<link id1="B" id2="C" />
<link id1="C" id2="I" />
```

Comment: And where is your XML parsing?

Comment: What shows `print_r($arr);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Steps

- Load the source XML.
- Create a destination document.
- Iterate the `<child>` elements.
- Fetch the `<link>` elements with the lowest age attribute via XPath.
- Create a link in the destination document for each returned link.

#### Code

```
$children = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$links = simplexml_load_string('<links/>');

foreach ($children->child as $child) {
    $youngestChild = $child->xpath(
        './link[
            not(@age > following-sibling::link/@age)
            and
            not(@age > preceding-sibling::link/@age)]
        '
    );
    $link = $links->addChild('link');
    $link->addAttribute('id1', $child['id']);
    $link->addAttribute('id2', $youngestChild[0]['id']);
}

echo $links->asXML();
```

#### Output (formatting mine):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<links>
    <link id1="A" id2="C"/>
    <link id1="B" id2="C"/>
    <link id1="C" id2="I"/>
 </links>
```

[Demo at codepad](http://codepad.org/ZA6OY9Ew) and here is an XPath tutorial for your convenience:

- http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the community :)

you can just use the [min()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) function to solve this problem.
no need to use a loop or anything.

who ever devoted this answer, explain why..

Comment: Welcome to the community. A downvote means your answer was deemed not useful by the downvoter. They don't need to be explained any further. In your particular case the downvote was because you do not show how or why the OP can use `min` to solve the problem. Provide an example please. You'll also likely realize then that `min` alone doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$strResult='';
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
foreach($xml->child as $child){
 $id1=$child['id'];
 $tid='';
 $tage=-1;
 foreach($child->link as $link){
    $id=$link['id'];$age=intval($link['age']);
    if($tage<0 || $tage>$age){
     $tage=$age;
     $tid=$id;
    }
 }
 $strResult.='<link id1="'.$id1.'" id2="'.$tid.'" />'."<br/>";
}
```

// $strResult has the desired result. This will work for any no of child elements having any number of link elements

Comment: also do not forget to check browser source if you use print($strResult);

Answer (score -1):

The structure of your code for sorting is correct, because if I write in the data from the xml file to an array directly, your code sorts it correctly.

The problem is in how you use the object created by simplexml_load_file. Also, you need to write the right print function to print only the bits you are interested in, once you have decided in which structure to get the input.

So, if I code the xml in an array, using different numbers for ages to force it to sort, I have:

```
    <?php
//$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
//$arr = (array) $xml;

$arr = array (array(  array("id" => "C",
                    "age" => "50",
                    ),
                array("id" => "B",
                        "age" => "30",
                ),
                array("id" => "H",
                        "age" => "12",
                )   
        ),
        array(  array("id" => "C",
                "age" => "50",
        ),
                array("id" => "D",
                        "age" => "10",
                )
        ),
        array(  array("id" => "I",
                "age" => "50",
                )
        )


        );

function find_youngest($task_1, $task_2) {
    if ($task_1['age'] === $task_2['age']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $task_1['age'] - $task_2['age'];
}

foreach ($arr as &$key) {
    usort($key, 'find_youngest');
}
//var_dump($arr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And the result of the output, basically of print_r($arr) is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => H
                    [age] => 12
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => B
                    [age] => 30
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => C
                    [age] => 50
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => D
                    [age] => 10
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => C
                    [age] => 50
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => I
                    [age] => 50
                )

        )

)
```

As you see $arr is now sorted by age. So you can get the age to print from the first element of each inner array.

The real problem in your code is therefore the initial part:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$arr = (array) $xml;
```

I guess you expect it to create arrays of arrays, while it creates objects of arrays of objects of arrays and so on all mixed up.

Comment: In summary, since your question is about finding the error in your code, the problem with your code is that you use the function usort to sort the <links> by age. usort sorts arrays, but the structure you build from the XML is not an array, but a more complex structure. Therefore, either you build an array like you want from the XML, or use a different function to sort the structure you build by age. It all depends by what you need in the rest of your program, or by the exercise requirements.